# How to send a file from my computer to my phone using KDE Connect?

Tags: android, kde-connect

I made sure that the `Share and receive` plugin of KDE Connect is enabled and the software installed both on my Android phone and my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop.

However, I can't find how to send a file from my laptop to my Android phone. Sending files from my Android phone to my laptop does work through my phone's share feature.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Open KDE Connect on the panel, and from there you will see a small folder icon on the right hand side , click on it, it will open you files on your phone.

If you are running Dolphin file manager split the screen so that you have your android on one side and your computer files on the other side. Drag-drop, copy-paste and have fun.

I found that I had to restart my phone after copying the files over to my phone to actually show up on my android system, but copying from phone to computer was instant.

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of the panel and the icon on the left hand side? Thanks!

Comment: see photo above in the top right hand corner is a little file icon that opens to your phone. Sorry my bad it is on the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't have such an icon on Ubuntu Unity 16.04. :-(

Comment: as far as I am aware KDE Connect is only for KDE and Kubuntu .

Comment: You need to add devices to be shared by file sharing in kde connect phone app.  Although I allowed it, I realized I needed to make folders or drives available.  This solved my problem.. not listed above

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in my laptop (Mint 18.3 cinnamon 64bits). I followed the [following instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/04/new-kde-connect-indicator-ubuntu-linux.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect
sudo apt update
sudo apt install indicator-kdeconnect kdeconnect
```

After that you can open `KDE Connect Indicator Settings` configure it, then open `indicator-kdeconnect` and the icon should appear in your computer's panel.

[image]

A tip for you: put the `indicator-kdeconnect` command in your `Startup Applications` list to enable it at log in, without the need to open it manually.

Comment: LM is not Ubuntu, it is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `kdeconnect-cli`. Typically something like:

If needed:

```sh
kdeconnect-cli -l
kdeconnect-cli --pair -d XXX
```

then

```sh
kdeconnect-cli -d XXX --share 'path/to/file'
```

Where `XXX` is device-id (16 char hex string).

---

## Beyond:

---

Using GNOME one can add GSConnect

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/
- https://github.com/GSConnect/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki

On Plasma I unfortunately have had some issues finding a good interface for SMS, but I might be missing something.

From the "Start Menu" one typically have something like:

[image]

Entering “Mobile Settings” I have:

[image]

Where I can set custom path for received files, and then also set up scripts for that folder (inotify etc.) One can also set up commands etc.

Notifications are sent to desktop (SMS, calls, etc.). I have KDE/GS icon in my head bar:

[image]

[image]

Which has a decent SMS GUI interface, share files option etc. ***Clicking the *share* icon at the end opens a file selector where file(s) to be sent can be selected.***

#### On the side:

It's easy to hack SMS by using

`.cache/gsconnect/XXX/sms.json`

`.cache/gsconnect/XXX/contacts.json`

where `XXX` is device ID.

which again can be used with `ckdeconnect-cli` if one desire.