# How can I transfer files from Ubuntu 22.04 using GSConnect to a Pixel7 using KDE Connect?

Tags: android, kde-connect

I have installed GSConnect and enabled it in the extensions app on my system running 22.04. I've also installed KDE Connect on my Pixel 7. I can connect the two systems, but I can only transfer files from android to the computer, and not vice versa. I haven't found any posts that address this problem.

Comment: Can you please be specific when you say you can only transfer files one way and not the other? Do you get an error? Did you try to do this and fail? Or do you not know how to do it? If you get an error, please include the full error verbatim. Also, [does this answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788223/how-to-send-a-file-from-my-computer-to-my-phone-using-kde-connect?rq=1)?

Comment: I have sense learned how to send files from Ubuntu to KDE Connect on the phone.